# No funciona el ejecutar animaciones en las cards cuando escucho el evento en Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos, animación, listener

No puedo lograr que anden los efectos al colocar el mouse encima de las cards ni tampoco ejecutar funciones dentro del addEventListener cuando se escucha cada evento para interactuar con las cards... probé haciendo las funciones dentro del mismo js donde generaba las cards y tampoco. No pude encontrar el error.  Quiero añadir efectos con jQuery solo poniendo el onmouseover y el onmouseout en las propiedades de donde deseo agregarlo.

```js
//DECLARACIÓN DE CLASE PRODUCTO
class Producto {
    constructor(id, nombre, precio, imagen) {
            this.id = parseInt(id);
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.precio = parseFloat(precio);
            this.imagen = imagen;
    }
}

//VARIABLES DE ACCESO GLOBAL
const productos = [];

//INSTANCIAR OBJETOS Y ASOCIAR A ARRAY GLOBAL
productos.push(new Producto(1, "Grade One", 7000, "fondo1.svg"));
productos.push(new Producto(2, "Fading", 7000, "fondo2.svg"));
productos.push(new Producto(3, "Midnigth Waves", 9000, "fondo3.svg"));
productos.push(new Producto(4, "GeoPattern", 12000, "fondo4.svg"));
console.log(productos);

//GENERAR INTERFAZ DE PRODUCTOS CON UNA FUNCION
productosUI(productos, '#productosContenedor');

let hover1 = document.getElementById("cardNFT");

//FUNCION PARA GENERAR LA INTERFAZ DE PRODUCTOS
function productosUI(productos, id){
    for (const producto of productos) {
       $(id).append
         (`
           <div class="card" id="cardNFT" style="width: 18rem;"
             onmouseover="classList.add('bg-dark', 'text-white');"
             onmouseout="classList.remove('bg-dark', 'text-white');">
             <img src="./imgs/${producto.imagen}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
               <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title">${producto.nombre}</h5>
                 <p class="card-text">$${producto.precio}</p>
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Comprar</a>
               </div>
           </div>
         `)

    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
<div class="card-column card-group" id="productosContenedor">
    <!--ACA SE GENERAN LOS PRODUCTOS-->
</div>
<!-- LIBRERIAS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Si usas jquery, por que no usar `$(body).mouseover(".card", function () {
    $(this).addClass('miClase');
})`? y lo mismo para el mouseLeave. Además, estás añadiendo la misma ID cardNFT multiples veces